# Jquery count caracter in p tag and add class

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery code that takes data from an input file and displays it on the screen.

Now I want jquery to count characters (and blank) and add a class to that, but depends of number of character:

1. if 1-3 characters = font size 36px
2. if 4-7 characters = font size 33px
3. if 8-12 characters = font size 30px

This is my current code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Get value on button click and show text
    $("#myBtn").click(function(){
        var str = $("#name").val();
        $('#one').html(str);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this

```js
$(function() {
  // Get value on button click and show text
  $("#myBtn").click(function() {
    const str = $("#name").val();
    let size = "one"; // default
    if (str.length < 4) size = "one"
    else if (str.length < 8) size = "four"
    else if (str.length < 13) size = "eight"
    $('#one')
      .html(str)
      .removeClass()
      .addClass(size)
  });
});
```

```css
.one {
  font-size: 36px
}

.four {
  font-size: 33px
}

.eight {
  font-size: 30px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="myBtn">Click</button>
<textarea id="name"></textarea>
<span id="one"></span>
```